# SQL con 2 tablas mezcladas de información

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 niveles de usuarios: MANAGERS y LEADERS. Ambos pueden levantar un query que llamaremos justificación.
Mi tabla de justificaciones tiene un campo llamado just_auth, eso almacena el ID de la persona que levantó la justificación. Mi problema viene cuando quiero recuperar la información. No se cómo decirle al query que si el MGR_ID viene vacío entonces recupere el LEAD_ID, en ambos hago un JOIN para sacar el nombre de la persona, no el ID.

Este es mi query actual

```
SELECT J.*, L.LEAD_NAME, E.EMP_NAME, JN.JUST_DESC
    FROM JUSTIFICATIONS J
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E
    ON J.JUST_NOMINA = E.EMP_ID
    INNER JOIN JUSTIFICATIONS_NAMES JN
    ON JN.ID_JUST = J.JUST_CAUSE
    INNER JOIN LEADERS L
    ON M.MGR_ID = J.JUST_AUTH
    WHERE MONTH(J.JUST_DATE)=MONTH(NOW())
    AND JUST_NOMINA = 4803563
    ORDER BY J.ID_JUSTIFY DESC
```

ese query lo ocupo en PHP para llenar una tabla que tengo aquí

```
<center>
        <h3>Justificaciones de Septiembre</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Motivo de la justificación</th>
                        <th>Tiempo justificado</th>
                        <th>Fecha de la justificación</th>
                        <th>Autorizó</th>
                        <th>Comentarios</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $output.='
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["JUST_DESC"].'</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["just_minutes"].'</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["just_date"].'</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">'.ucwords(strtolower($row["LEAD_NAME"])).'</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["just_comments"].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                $output.='</tbody>
            </table>
        </center>';
```

El problema es que si JUST_AUTH no es un LEADER, entonces deberá ser un MANAGER, eso si me sale si lo separo. Pero no entiendo cómo resolverlo si la misma persona tuvo 2 justificaciones, 1 por cada nivel. ¿Cómo tendría que armar el query o el PHP?, me imagino que sería algo así en el WHILE:

```
if($row["LEAD_NAME"]==null)
{
 $output.= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.ucwords(strtolower($row["MGR_NAME"])).'</td>';
}

else
{
$output.= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.ucwords(strtolower($row["LEAD_NAME"])).'</td>';
}
```

Pero si es de ambos... no se que hacer. Ósea como poner un LEAD_NAME y un MGR_NAME mezclado, y es que si recupero los dos nombres en el query no me trae nada, Así lo hice:

```
SELECT J.*, L.LEAD_NAME, E.EMP_NAME, JN.JUST_DESC, M.MGR_NAME
    FROM JUSTIFICATIONS J
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E
    ON J.JUST_NOMINA = E.EMP_ID
    INNER JOIN JUSTIFICATIONS_NAMES JN
    ON JN.ID_JUST = J.JUST_CAUSE
    INNER JOIN LEADERS L
    ON L.LEAD_ID = J.JUST_AUTH
    INNER JOIN MANAGERS M
    ON M.MGR_ID = J.JUST_AUTH
    WHERE MONTH(J.JUST_DATE)=MONTH(NOW())
    AND JUST_NOMINA = 4803563
    ORDER BY J.ID_JUSTIFY DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal si ajustas el query del procedimiento almacenado para que uses LEFT OUTER JOIN en lugar de INNER JOIN para las consultas que dependen del campo Just_Auth, algo como así:

```
SELECT J.*, ISNULL(L.LEAD_NAME,'') AS LEAD_NAME , E.EMP_NAME, JN.JUST_DESC,ISNULL(M.MGR_NAME,'') AS MGR_NAME
FROM JUSTIFICATIONS J
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON J.JUST_NOMINA = E.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN JUSTIFICATIONS_NAMES JN ON JN.ID_JUST = J.JUST_CAUSE
LEFT OUTER JOIN LEADERS L ON L.LEAD_ID = J.JUST_AUTH
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANAGERS M ON M.MGR_ID = J.JUST_AUTH
WHERE MONTH(J.JUST_DATE)=MONTH(NOW())
AND JUST_NOMINA = 4803563
ORDER BY J.ID_JUSTIFY DESC
```

Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto colega! Me has salvado el pellejo. Solo que en MySQL es IFNULL. Saludos ;D

Comment: Con gusto amigo, me alegra que te haya servido. Saludos.